# How to run a Cucumber-JVM feature file from the command line

Tags: java, cucumber-jvm

I have a file with file extension `.feature`. HOw do run this from the command line?

In order to make a batch file for each feature. I am using [Cucumber-JVM](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm) with Java and [Selenium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_%28software%29).

Answer (score 3):

Cucumber-JVM is based on JUnit so its just like running any unit tests from the command line

```
java -cp /path/to/junit.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore [test class name]
```

where `test class name` is annotated with [`@CucumberOptions`](http://cucumber.github.io/api/cucumber/jvm/javadoc/cucumber/api/CucumberOptions.html) whose [`features`](http://cucumber.github.io/api/cucumber/jvm/javadoc/cucumber/api/CucumberOptions.html#features--)
refer to the feature file. If youre using Maven you could use

```
mvn test
```

Comment: this error keeps displaying when i attempt to run the line you provided JUnit version 4.4
Could not find class: test.feature

Time: 0

OK (0 tests)

Comment: add the location of your test class to the classpath

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Maven, you can run your `.feature` file this way:

```
mvn -Dcucumber.options="from/the/root/of/module/to/the/feature/MyFeature.feature" test
```

This will override the `@CucumberOptions` in the test runner class.

Answer (score 0):

You can run any test runner or override default test runner by using the command line below. This means you only want to run the test named SmokeTestRunner. By the way, you are free to set surefire plugin in your pom.xml any way. For example, you can set up your surefire plugin in your pom.xml to run the regression test named RegressionTestRunner. It doesn't matter.

> mvn *-Dtest=**/SmokeTestRunner.java* test

Your SmokeTestRunner java file should look like this. ->

```
@CucumberOptions(
features = "src/test/resources/features/Smoke.feature",
glue = {"stepdefinitions", "hooks"},
tags = "@chrome", // It runs only scenarios tagged with "@chrome"
plugin = {"pretty"/*you can add more cucumber plugins here if you want.*/},
monochrome = true)
public class SmokeTestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {}
```

For more details, have a look at the maven surefire plugin docs. (https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html)