# How do I run from command line my cucumber java features developed with Intellij and with junit-4.12.jar

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber, bdd, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I create my cucumber java feature on Intellij IDE and I can run my feature test with the IDE. But now I need to run these tests with the command line. So I have my doubts about how do I execute it.

There is my project structure:

```
├── CucumberPOC.iml
└── src
    └── test
        ├── CucumberRunner.java
        ├── java
        │   ├── CheeseStepDefinition.java
        │   └── StepDefinition.java
        └── resources
            ├── cheese.feature
            └── myfeature.feature
```

I am using junit-4.12.jar library. I am trying to execute the command used as answer for the question: **[How to run a Cucumber-JVM feature file from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23324507/how-to-run-a-cucumber-jvm-feature-file-from-the-command-line)**. But it command doesn't work for me and I will like to run all my suite or an specific feature.

Also I want to run the command without ***maven***. Just a simple command like:

```
java  library_path arguments_my_features....
```

I don't know how to use the java commands to run feature(s), it is my problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run a Cucumber-JVM feature file from the command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23324507/how-to-run-a-cucumber-jvm-feature-file-from-the-command-line)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30586937/how-to-run-cucumber-file-from-command-line